# What is the best way to escape this infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops

Here's the relevant part of my code..

```
static void salesSlip( String[] day)
{
    // for each employee
    for (int i = 0; i < salesArray[0].length; i++)
    {   
        int employeeNo = i + 1;
        System.out.printf("Employee %d please enter sales details for %s\n", employeeNo, day[i]);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");

        // for each product chosen call dailySales  
        System.out.println("Please enter product number or -1 when finished");
        int productNo = input.nextInt();

        while (productNo != -1)
        {
            dailySales(productNo, employeeNo);
        }
    }

}

static void dailySales(int product, int employeeNo)
{
    System.out.printf("Enter total value of sales for product %d:", product);
    int sales = input.nextInt();
    salesArray[product][employeeNo] = sales; 
}
```

When I enter a number that is not -1 dailySales() gets called and when I enter a number in dailySales() it gets called again and again.

Sample output:

### Employee 1 please enter sales details for Monday

Please enter product number or -1 when finished 1
Enter total value of sales for product 1:2
Enter total value of sales for product 1:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `while` loop, nothing changes the value of `productNo`, so it will be an infinite loop.

Prompt the user and get more input, changing `productNo` again at the bottom of the `while` loop.

```
System.out.println("Please enter product number or -1 when finished");
int productNo = input.nextInt();

while (productNo != -1)
{
    dailySales(productNo, employeeNo);

    System.out.println("Please enter product number or -1 when finished");
    productNo = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is that you assign a value to productno only once (just before the while loop)
Then you call dailySales, where the value for productno is not changed. When you return from dailySales, productno has not changed (in your example,it is still 1).
Then the while loop checks the value of productno again, and calls dailySales again.

What you miss is asking (and reading) a new value for productno, after the call to dailySales, inside the while loop.